# Create an evolutive YAML configuration parser

Tags: python, yaml

For my Python application, I need to create a configuration file parser that will be able to parse multiple versions of the config file.

The aim is to create a configuration parser that will be safe whatever the version of the config file.

Take the following example: today I am sending my software and a specific configuration file to my client. Tomorrow, I will release a new software revision. How can I ensure its compatibility with the config file sent today? And for the next software revisions?

Here is an example: say I have the `config_1.yaml` configuration file:

```
version: 1
digits:
  - one
  - two
  - three
```

I want my Python to read:

```
{'digits': ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'version': 1}
```

Then some time later, I am updating my configuration files format as `config_2.yaml`:

```
version: 2
digits:
  - one
  - two
  - three

colors:
  red: #FF0000
  green: #00FF00
  blue: #0000FF
```

I want my software to read this configuration as:

```
{'colors': {'blue': '#0000FF', 'green': '#00FF00', 'red': '#FF0000'},
 'digits': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
 'version': 2}
```

**But** I also need this software version to be able and read `config_1.yaml` as:

```
{'colors': [], 'digits': ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'version': 1}
```

And so on: when a third software version is released, I want it to be able and read `config_3.yaml`:

```
version: 3
digits:
  - one
  - two
  - three

colors:
  red: '#FF0000'
  green: '#00FF00'
  blue: '#0000FF'

constants:
  pi: 3.1415
  e: 2.71828
```

As:

```
{'colors': {'blue': '#0000FF', 'green': '#00FF00', 'red': '#FF0000'},
 'constants': {'e': 2.71828, 'pi': 3.1415},
 'digits': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
 'version': 3}
```

And for `config_1.yaml` and `config_2.yaml` respectively:

```
{'colors': [], 'constants': {}, 'digits': ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'version': 1}

{'colors': {'blue': '#0000FF', 'green': '#00FF00', 'red': '#FF0000'},
 'constants': {},
 'digits': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
 'version': 2}
```

I wrote the following code to get these results:

```py
import yaml
from pprint import pprint


def read_yaml(f_path):
    with open(f_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fid:
        config = yaml.load(fid, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    return config


def read_config_1(config):
    pass


def read_config_2(config):
    if config['version'] < 2:
        read_config_1(config)
        # the "colors" part of the config was added between versions 1 and 2
        config['colors'] = []


def read_config_3(config):
    if config['version'] < 3:
        read_config_2(config)
        # the "constants" part of the config was added between versions 2 and 3
        config['constants'] = {}


def read_config_file(f_path):
    config = read_yaml(f_path)
    read_config_3(config)
    return config


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for f_name in [f'config_{i}.yaml' for i in range(1, 4)]:
        print('-'*20 + ' ' + f_name + ' ' + '-'*20)
        config = read_config_file(f_name)
        pprint(config)
        print()
```

Has anybody any comments on this code, or any advice on how (more) efficient it can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bit cumbersome to maintain. The default values
are is spread out over multiple values, there is no encapsulation.

You should just make a
configuration class, derived from `dict` (assuming  you want
it to work as `dict` with subscriptions). Its `__init__` should
initialise all values for the latest version to sensible values (empty
lists, dict, etc.). After that you read the YAML file and overwrite the values
you find in there.

```
from pprint import pprint
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

CONFIG_VERSION = 3  # latest version number used in config files

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')

class Config(dict):
   def __init__(self, file_name):
       self['constants'] = {}  # added version 3
       self['colors'] = []     # added version 2
       if not hasattr(file_name, 'open'):
           file_name = Path(file_name)
       d = yaml.load(file_name)
       if d['version'] > CONFIG_VERSION:
           print("don't know how to handle newer config version", d['version'])
       # optionally do something special for some versions
       # if d['version'] < NR:
       #      self.update_from_NR(d)
       # else: 
       self.update(d)
       d['version'] = CONFIG_VERSION  # in case you dump the config


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for f_name in [f'config_{i}.yaml' for i in range(1, 4)]:
        print('-'*20 + ' ' + f_name + ' ' + '-'*20)
        config = Config(f_name)
        pprint(config)
        print()
```

which gives:

```
-------------------- config_1.yaml --------------------
{'colors': [], 'constants': {}, 'digits': ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'version': 1}

-------------------- config_2.yaml --------------------
{'colors': {'blue': None, 'green': None, 'red': None},
 'constants': {},
 'digits': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
 'version': 2}

-------------------- config_3.yaml --------------------
{'colors': {'blue': '#0000FF', 'green': '#00FF00', 'red': '#FF0000'},
 'constants': {'e': 2.71828, 'pi': 3.1415},
 'digits': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
 'version': 3}
```

I don't think using PyYAML's FullConstructor helps you make better
config files, safe-constructing and using explict tags for any
constructions you want tagged, is better and more user friendly.

You can of course do the above in PyYAML, assuming you really only
want to support YAML 1.1 (which was superceded by YAML 1.2 in 2009, almost 10
years ago now), and only need the subset of 1.1 that PyYAML
can load. (Disclaimer: I am the author of ruamel.yaml)

Comment: That is the approach I imagined at first. But I believe that I need to always keep in mind all the previous versions in order to be able and parse them. I thought my approach allowed me to be iterative. Am I wrong?

Comment: In your approach you *have* to be iterative, in my approach you *can* be iterative.  Nothing prevents you from checking the version number and calling a method to do some transformation, I'll update the answer to make that clear.

Comment: Great! I believe that is the easiest and clearest code to make thé job. Thx

Comment: One afterthought: you should set `self['version']` to the latest config version at the end of `__init__`, especially if you intend to write out the config again.